# How to listen to Metamask's web3's "confirm"/"cancel" event of a contract?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

Since metamask's injected web3 follows https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

But there seems to be no coding to catch the confirm/cancel button clicking event (img below) when calling contract.new()

[image: metamask's pop for user to confirm/cancel]

Is there a way to catch the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user clicked the 'cancel' button, the 'processedContract' variable below will be undefined.

If confirmed, it will be the contract and if it has an address ( processedContract.address ) then it is being mined.

```
newContract.new({...}, function(e, processedContract) {...});
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle Confirm/Cancel response of user on your contract functions, you can use the **transactionHash** event & **error** event from send function.

> "transactionHash" returns transactionHash: String: Fired when the transaction hash is available.

> "error" returns error: Error: Fired if an error occurs during sending. If the transaction was rejected by the network with a receipt, the receipt will be available as a property on the error object.[image]

[You can see detail here.](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#id36)

When you click on **Confirm** button then you can handle this case in the **transactionHash** event.

When you click on **Cancel** button then you can handle this case in the **error** event.